# How to use ECS Service Daemon Scheduling with CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

AWS recently added daemon scheduling to ECS (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/06/amazon-ecs-adds-daemon-scheduling/), but I couldn't find how to configure it inside a CloudFormation template.

Not sure if the docs were not updated or it is not available yet.

Comment: It's a real problem that AWS releases feature without CloudFormation support, while a third party software like Terraform already has the scheduling option available (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_service.html#daemon-scheduling-strategy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it has been officially some time ago

Source: [AWS::ECS::Service @ awsdocs](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/blob/main/doc_source/aws-resource-ecs-service.md)

Comment: Unfortunately for my use case I still need them to implement the --pid support on ECS TaskDefinition :(

Answer (score 0):

Today, I got this feedback from the AWS support:

> Sebastian, I checked my end and I see that it is not currently supported via Cloudformation.
>   But the good news is, there is an open feature request with out Cloudformation service team and they are actively working on adding this feature to cloudformation
>   In my experience, I have seen new features released will be added to cloudformation I will go ahead and add your interest to the feature request which can potentially increase the priority of it.